# Can't use for-in loop in function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not sure why this for-in loop isn't working. I'm using a slider that calls `valueChanged:` whenever it moves. To simplify the code I cleaned up all my stuff, but I just want to know why this doesn't work:

```
- (void)valueChanged:(CCControlSlider *)sender{
        for(CCControlSlider *slider in self.arrayOfSliders){
            NSLog(@"do something");
        }
}
```

It crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Am I doing something illegal here? Thanks

** EDIT:
The issue: self.arrayOfSliders was set to (nonatomic, assign), so it wasn't being retained.

I've set my project to ARC (I'm more used to it!), problem should be solved. Thank you!

Comment: Try to use this "simplified" code instead of yours, will it work ?

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates `self.arrayOfSliders`? My guess is that you never retained it, and therefore it gets released before you access it in the above code.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS looks like memory problem to me, ARC enabled?

Comment: Do you see any of the log statements? Is this `valueChanged:` even called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What debugging have you done? Is self.arrayOfSliders a valid object that hasn't been released?

Checking that a pointer is returned isn't enough. Try turning on [NSZombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) to see if the object has been deallocated.

Comment: Not really an answer, @Wain. Questions go in the Comments section. This could be couched as an answer, though; for example, you could give advice on what debugging the OP should do.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't comment yet, not enough reps. But when I can, I will. Thanks